# Best graph to show multiple data types

Tags: user-expectation, user-centered-design, charts, best-practice

I've got a design a dashboard regarding a sample data set! The data I use is the population in US. I've come up with some data which has multiple figure types such as percentages, amounts, USD rates and such. The following link has some of the data I'm going to use.

[data link](http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/01000.html)

In the above link, say I want to show the amount of housing units, Homeownership rate, Median value of owner-occupied housing units in a single graph. Is it logical to take these facts up into a single graph or is there a better way of showing the data with relevant logical relationships in a dashboard using charts.

Comment: Is there a time series to this graph, or are you literally trying to show just 4 different numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's never good idea to put so many informations into single graph. Graph should clearly states what is presented. You will have difficulties to add headlines or axis description that don't confuse user. If you lack of space you can always add some tabs so user can switch between graphs. I would strongly discourage to put all of that information in single place.

Answer (score 1):

If a unit of measure is universal across all that data that you are trying to display then I think it is fine to use same graph. For example the facebook metrics: [image]

it uses the same graph to display three different values: likes, comments, shares

But I do not foresee how you can display housing units, ownership rates, median, etc all in a single graph as the units of measure in that, I would imagine, be different from each other. So I suggest using separate graphs for each data that is measured in its own unique unit of measure.